# Does Mod Deflate automatically cache the defalted files?

Tags: apache, apache2

I am using mod_deflate to compress javascript files. I want to know if the deflated files are cached somewhere or the files are compressed everytime they are requested for.

If they are cached, is there a way to configure the cache to improve the performance or tweak the settings ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

NO,

you can tell the browsers to cache it on there end aswell my using

```
a2enmod expires
```

and to configure mod expire you need to do this inside this file
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
          <FilesMatch "\.(jpe?g|png|gif|js|css)$">
                      ExpiresActive On
                      ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"
          </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

test in the browser.

Now if you want to use more advanced caching they why not use varnish. If you have static content varnish will make you website fly and less burden on your apache.